# Fabric 1.16.5 development Crash on launch: Error initialising mixin config mineralsplus.mixins.json

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm trying start modding (I chose fabric) and I'm very much confused by this error that it throws when I try to run Minecraft.

Crash Log:

```
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.Config.create(Config.java:153)
Config.java:153
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixins.createConfiguration(Mixins.java:100)
Mixins.java:100
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixins.addConfiguration(Mixins.java:87)
Mixins.java:87
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.common.FabricMixinBootstrap.addConfiguration(FabricMixinBootstrap.java:44)
FabricMixinBootstrap.java:44
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
Iterable.java:75
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.common.FabricMixinBootstrap.init(FabricMixinBootstrap.java:83)
FabricMixinBootstrap.java:83
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:132)
Knot.java:132
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:28)
KnotClient.java:28
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Main.java:86
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified resource 'mineralsplus.mixins.json' was invalid or could not be read
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinConfig.create(MixinConfig.java:1090)
MixinConfig.java:1090
    at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.Config.create(Config.java:148)
Config.java:148
    ... 8 more
```

File Structure:

[image: File Structure]

I don't have a lot of experience with fabric, so I followed a tutorial on YouTube and I still can't figure out what the issue is.

As of what I understand it seems to not find `mineralsplus.mixins.json`?

Here are the contents of `mineralsplus.mixins.json` :

```json
{
  "required": true,
  "minVersion": "0.8",
  "package": "hukyfi.minerals.plus.mixin",
  "compatibilityLevel": "JAVA_8",
  "mixins": [
  ],
  "client": [
    "ExampleMixin"
  ],
  "injectors": {
    "defaultRequire": 1
  }
}
```

This might be the dumbest mistake on my side and I apologise if that's the case. But, thanks for taking the time to read through my post,

Huky

Comment: Can you provide your build.gradle as well? I can't see anything wrong with what you have shown, but some build configuration options are required for mixins to work properly. The documentation by spongepowered for mixins is [here](https://docs.spongepowered.org/stable/en-PT/plugin/internals/mixins.html), for more specific information. It is also worth noting that you might not even need to apply mixins, considering that you are inexperienced using fabric. It may be helpful if you specified what your intended goal is - if this error is just a result of you trying to set up the fabric workspace,

Comment: I just tried to setup the workspace correctly using the example mod file. And I figured out my mistake: Actually everything was correct in the files, I just had to select the right java version in the Config Java Runtime pannel and just restart VSCode. I keep making this mistake over and over haha, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I fixed it.

I have multiple versions of Java installed on my machine and VSCode just picked the latest one which caused the error. I just had to open the Configure Java Runtime panel using the command palette (`cmd/CTRL+Shift+P`) and switch the java version of the project to use `Java 1.8`.